# Typescript: enum index from database gives type error

Tags: typescript, types

In my Discord bot, I have an enum with the moderation icons:

```
export enum moderationIcon {
    ban = '',
    kick = '',
    pardon = '',
    warn = ''
}
```

And when I create the moderation history I want to add the icon like this: `moderationIcon[moderationRow.type.toLowerCase()]`, but I've got this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof moderationIcon'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof moderationIcon'.

How to solve this kind of error?

(the `moderationRow.type` is either 'BAN', 'KICK', PARDON' or 'WARN')

Comment: Try `moderationIcon[moderationRow.type.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof moderationIcon]`

Comment: How about uppercasing the enum keys? Is there a reason one needs to be uppercase and the other lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return-type of `toLowerCase()` is `string`, which is more generic than `'typeof moderationIcon'`.

I think the closest and typesafest thing you can achieve at the moment is writing a getter function using [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#lowercasestringtype) that were added in typescript 4.1. It involves a cast though:

```
function getModerationIcon(type: Uppercase<keyof typeof moderationIcon>) {
  return moderationIcon[type.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof moderationIcon]
}
```